# force "npx browserslist@latest --update-db"

Tags: npm, terminal, npx

I'm using `npx browserslist@latest --update-db` as part of my npm build process but sometimes it hangs waiting for user input:

```
Need to install the following packages:
browserslist@4.21.2
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

I run it as a script in my package.json

How do I skip that part and make it "auto-yes" in terminal so that my build process is not interrupted?

Can't find any info on that. Is that possible at all? I can't find any "-force" option for that so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be nowadays `npx --yes browserslist@latest --update-db`

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this myself, and determined that the *Need to install the following packages* prompt is actually coming from npx, which has a `--yes` option that lets you auto-confirm prompts. Try this:

```
npx browserslist@latest --update-db --yes
```

(Updated per Rolf's comment)

Comment: ERROR: You must supply a command.

Comment: The `--yes` is in the wrong location, it should be:
`npx browserslist@latest --update-db --yes`